# Null pointer exception thrown by DataOutputStream mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm writing unit tests (with Mockito as my mocking library) for a class that wraps a TCP socket. The problem is that any test which calls writeBytes on a DataOutputStream is throwing a null pointer exception.

I've included three pieces of information below:

1) The class under test, TCPClient

2) The unit tests, TCPClientTest. The tests that fail are testSendWhileActive() and testSendWhileInactive()

3) A stack trace of the null pointer exception

I've run the test in a debugger and verified that the parameter passed to dataOutStreamFact.get is not null, nor is its return. I've included the identifiers for both below:

OutputStream$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$344932e5  (id=74)

mOutStream  DataOutputStream$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$4499185f  (id=114)

One thing that appears unusual is the source of the NPE. It occurs in DataOutputStream.java at line 276, which attempts to write to the underlying output stream. I can only assume that we wouldn't execute any code in DataOutputStream if my mock was created correctly.

**Class under test: TCPClient**

```
package com.plined.arenavideos;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TCPClient extends Thread {

    PacketListener mListener;
    boolean mActive;
    Socket mSocket;
    DataOutputStream mOutStream;
    BufferedReader mInStream;

    public TCPClient(String ip, int port, PacketListener listener, 
            SocketFactory sockFact, DataOutputStreamFactory dataOutStreamFact,
            BufferedReaderFactory buffReadFact) throws IOException {
        mActive = true;
        mSocket = sockFact.get(ip, port);
        mOutStream = dataOutStreamFact.get(mSocket.getOutputStream());
        mInStream = buffReadFact.get(mSocket.getInputStream());
        mListener = listener;
    }

    /*
     * Deactivates this tcp client so it no longer
     * sends and listens to packets.
     */
    public void deactive() {
        mActive = false;
    }

    /*
     */
    public void run() {
        beginListening();
    }

    /*
     * Begins listening for packets from the socket
     * and passes them on to listeners when found.
     */
    void beginListening() {
        while(true) {
            getPacket();
        }
    }

    void getPacket() {
        try {
            String input = mInStream.readLine();

            if (input == null) {
                //TODO: Make it notify the manager here instead. SO it can cleanup.
                throw new RuntimeException("Connection to master has died.");
            }

            if (mActive) {
                System.out.println("Received data from master " + input);
                mListener.processPacket(input);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error while receiving from stream");
        }
    }


    /*
     * Sends the provided data using the TCP socket.
     */
    public void send(String data) throws IOException {
        if (mActive) {
            mOutStream.writeBytes(data);
        }
    }

    public interface IFactory {
        public TCPClient get(String ip, int port);
    }

    public interface SocketFactory {
        public Socket get(String ip, int port);
    }

    public interface DataOutputStreamFactory {
        public DataOutputStream get(OutputStream stream);
    }

    public interface BufferedReaderFactory {
        public BufferedReader get(InputStream stream);
    }

}
```

**Unit Tests: TCPClientTest**

```
package com.plined.arenavideos;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import com.plined.arenavideos.TCPClient.BufferedReaderFactory;
import com.plined.arenavideos.TCPClient.DataOutputStreamFactory;
import com.plined.arenavideos.TCPClient.SocketFactory;

public class TCPClientTest {

    Socket mockSocket;
    DataOutputStream mockDataOutStream;
    BufferedReader mockBufferedReader;

    SocketFactory mockSocketFactory;
    DataOutputStreamFactory mockDataOutputStreamFactory;
    BufferedReaderFactory mockBufferedReaderFactory;

    PacketListener mockListener;

    TCPClient clientUnderTest;

    static final String packetData = "newJob^20^/home/perry/work/test.mp4^/home/perry/work/test_converted.mp4\n";

    @Before
    public void setup() throws IOException {
        //Create our factory returns
        mockSocket = mock(Socket.class);
        when(mockSocket.getOutputStream()).thenReturn(mock(OutputStream.class));
        when(mockSocket.getInputStream()).thenReturn(mock(InputStream.class));

        mockDataOutStream = mock(DataOutputStream.class);

        mockBufferedReader = mock(BufferedReader.class);

        mockSocketFactory = mock(SocketFactory.class);
        when(mockSocketFactory.get(anyString(), anyInt())).thenReturn(mockSocket);

        mockDataOutputStreamFactory = mock(DataOutputStreamFactory.class);
        when(mockDataOutputStreamFactory.get(any(OutputStream.class))).thenReturn(mockDataOutStream);

        mockBufferedReaderFactory = mock(BufferedReaderFactory.class);
        when(mockBufferedReaderFactory.get(any(InputStream.class))).thenReturn(mockBufferedReader);

        mockListener = mock(PacketListener.class);

        clientUnderTest = new TCPClient("52.50.30.25", 25200, mockListener, mockSocketFactory, mockDataOutputStreamFactory, mockBufferedReaderFactory);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetPacketPassToListener() throws IOException {
        when(mockBufferedReader.readLine()).thenReturn(packetData);
        clientUnderTest.getPacket();
        verify(mockListener).processPacket(packetData);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetPacketDontPassAsInactive() throws IOException {
        when(mockBufferedReader.readLine()).thenReturn(packetData);
        clientUnderTest.deactive();
        clientUnderTest.getPacket();
        verify(mockListener, never()).processPacket(packetData);
    }

    @Test(expected=RuntimeException.class)
    public void testGetPacketFailedConnection() throws IOException {
        String packetData = null;
        when(mockBufferedReader.readLine()).thenReturn(packetData);
        clientUnderTest.getPacket();
    }


    //TODO: Fix this test.
    //@Test
    public void testSendWhileActive() throws IOException {
        clientUnderTest.send(packetData);
        verify(mockDataOutStream).writeBytes(packetData);
    }

    //TODO: Fix this test.
    //@Test
    public void testSendWhileInactive() throws IOException {
        clientUnderTest.deactive();
        clientUnderTest.send(packetData);
        verify(mockDataOutStream, never()).writeBytes(packetData);
    }
}
```

**Stack trace of testSendWhileActive**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeBytes(DataOutputStream.java:276)
    at com.plined.arenavideos.TCPClient.send(TCPClient.java:77)
    at com.plined.arenavideos.TCPClientTest.testSendWhileActive(TCPClientTest.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Usually you would use `verify()` with `@Spy`'es.

Comment: That is a lot of mocks... Do you really need _all_ of them?

Comment: fge, I believe I do need all of the mocks, though I might be mistaken. All of them are roughly related. If the socket is mocked, the resulting output and input streams from it have to be mocked, presumably.

Comment: I believe I have found the problem... Unfortunately we don't use the same JDK so sources differ. Can you check in your JDK source what is at DataOutputStream.java line 276? If my guess is correct, it is a line which would read `out.write(...);` -- and `out` is an instance variable of `FilterOutputStream`

Comment: Line 276: out.write((byte)s.charAt(i));

You're correct, it is of type FilterOutputStream.

Comment: The problem is there imho: `out` is null. You'd need to rework your test so as to properly initialize `DataOutputStream`, or mock whatever write method is used. But this is becoming quite a challenge at this point...

Comment: Appreciate the help, fge. You're correct, it is null there. That's unusual, I must be instantiating my factory incorrectly. I'll see if I can sort it out. Thank you!

Comment: Note: as you are using mockito, you may work around this by using `doNothing()`. Ie, `doNothing().when(whateverIsRelevant).relevantMethod(any());`. That can be one way to cure the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's expected, Mockito can't mock final methods or class and `java.io.DataOutputStream.writeBytes(...)` is final. The `DataOutputStream` class is not `final` and has both `final` and non `final` `public` methods so it's reasonable that Mockito don't warn you when creating the mock.

Also as one of the mockito commiter I strongly advise you to not mock types you don't own. There's several good reasons for that. One of them being if you mock something, and the library tweaks or just change the behavior your tests won't be able to detect it, and this code may fail in production, i.e. at the worst moment !

Instead you should definitely rewrite this test, by asserting on the expected data.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, Brice. I appreciate it. I've marked your response as the answer.

Do you have any suggestions on how I can unit test this code without mocking types that I don't own? I want to be able to verify that in a given situation a specific call is made to write data to the output stream.

I had considered writing a class to wrap BufferedReader and DataOutputStream so I could then create a mock out of it and test for expected interactions. Is that a suitable alternative? Or do you have another suggestion?

Comment: Well I'm not sure what you're trying to do precisely,but from what I gather from the posted snippets, the first thing I'll do is to use real DataOutputSteam/BufferedReader.

Comment: After a long edit : From what I gather on the posted snippets the first thing I'll do is to use real `DataOutputSteam`/`BufferedReader`,maybe you can find more practical to use `OutputStream`/`Reader` interfaces so you can use more practical types for the test.If you're on the packet receiving you just craft a `BufferedReader` from a string then assert the content passed to the listener. And when dealing with sending you'll just assert that the passed string matches the content in the DPS. That's just a start, from there you can keep enhancing the code (including the test code) ; that's TDD ;)